# How to develop a Netbeans Platform Application in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans-platform

For me, Eclipse is the IDE to work with when I like to develop a Java application. But I like Swing more than SWT, so I'd like to use the Netbeans Platform for my Application.

Is it possible to develop a Netbeans Platform application in Eclipse? Where can I find information about this?

Comment: I just accepted that I would have to use the two IDEs, one for web and other desktop. I hope someday to change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting out on a great endeavour, and I want to congratulate you on your decision.

With me it is just the same. I love working with MyEclipse and Pulse. To me the Eclispe JDT are still superior to what the NetBeans IDE Editor offers - though I really have to say that the NetBeans Development Team is doing well on catching up ...

Ok, I was just reminded that this is only about questions and answers, so here is the answer:

!!! YES !!! you can develop with Eclipse for NetBeans Platform !!! BUT !!! it will be painful. Using Maven can help - but you will still forfeit all the wirzards available from within NetBeans IDE eventually finding yourself writing a lot of code which could have been generated for you.

In order to stop messing up the Q&A paradigm of this site I would love to refer you the following link on Geertjan's Blog:

http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/let_s_get_that_netbeans

I frequently revisit this entry to see if there are any new thoughts. Feel free to post there. As far as I can tell this is the best information around at the moment.

Best regards,

Thomas G.